# decode_json error getting error because of encoding issue

Tags: json, perl

I'm getting an error executing the following code:

```
use JSON;
use Encode qw( encode decode encode_utf8 decode_utf8);
my $arr_features_json = '[{"family":"1","id":107000,"unit":"","parent_id":"0","cast":"2","search_values_range":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12","category_id":"29","type":"2","position":"3","name":"Número de habitaciones","code":"numberofrooms","locales":"4","flags":"1"}]';
$arr_features_json = decode_json( $arr_features_json );
```

The following is the error I get:

> malformed UTF-8 character in JSON string, at character offset 169 (before "\x{fffd} de habitaci...") at test.pl line 13.

`decode_json` is issuing the error because of the `ú` character in the json, so I want to convert this character to `\u00fa`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that string you are trying to process is not an [`UTF-8`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or faulty UTF-8 string. So, you need to convert it to UTF-8 string using `encode_utf8` before decoding it to json.

```
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode qw( encode decode encode_utf8 decode_utf8);

my $arr_features_json = '[{"family":"1","id":107000,"unit":"","parent_id":"0","cast":"2","search_values_range":"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12","category_id":"29","type":"2","position":"3","name":"Número de habitaciones","code":"numberofrooms","locales":"4","flags":"1"}]';
my $arr_features = decode_json( encode_utf8($arr_features_json) );

print Dumper($arr_features);
```

Probably you should check a this [`article`](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/08/know-the-difference-between-character-strings-and-utf-8-strings/) to know difference between `UTF-8` strings and `character strings`.

Comment: This is backwards. `decode_json` expects a UTF-8 string (octets) but the input contains a "wide character". `encode_utf8` converts a string that is not UTF-8 encoded into a string that is. (Well, it can also convert a string that is already UTF-8 encoded into one that is doubly encoded)

Comment: The code is right, but both sentences of the explanation are backwards.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami corrected. I didn't noticed it before.

Answer (score 2):

`decode_json` expects UTF-8, but the string you have isn't encoded using UTF-8. `decode` the string if it's not already, then use `from_json` instead of `decode_json`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use utf8;                             # Perl code is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';  # Terminal provides/expects UTF-8.

use JSON qw( from_json );

my $features_json = '
  [
    {
      "family": "1",
      "id": 107000,
      "unit": "",
      "parent_id": "0",
      "cast": "2",
      "search_values_range": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12",
      "category_id": "29",
      "type": "2",
      "position": "3",
      "name": "Número de habitaciones",
      "code": "numberofrooms",
      "locales": "4",
      "flags": "1"
    }
  ]
';

my $features = from_json( $features_json );

say $features->[0]{name};
```